# Why the group do not shows its users(it contains the test02) in user_set?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a user `test02`, and you can see there is `售后组 group` in its groups:

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "account": null,
        "last_login": null,
        "username": "test02",
        ...
        "is_admin": false,
        "is_staff": false,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "status": "1",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "售后组",
                "permissions": [
                    13
                ]
            }
        ],
        "user_permissions": []
    }
```

But when I use `group.user_set` to check the group's users, it shows `None`.

```
try:
    group = Group.objects.get(pk=group_id)  # there I get `售后组 group`
    users = group.user_set

    for user in users:
        message = Message.objects.create(
            title = title,
            content = content,
            create_user = create_user,

        )
        message.save()
        message.receive_user.add(user)

except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Why the `售后组 group` do not shows its users(it contains the `test02`)?

Comment: please try users =  group.user_set.all(). And please note The _set object is made available when related_name is not specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
users = group.user_set
```

Try:

```
users = group.user_set.all()
```